# Kaa - Maven repository for building Custom log appender

Tags: kaa

https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Customization-guide/Customizable-system-components/Log-appenders/

The above link gives an example of the Maven POM required to build the log appender. Are the dependencies available in the central maven repository ? (I dont think so)

So is the below repository configuration required in the POM ?

```
<repository>
            <id>repository.kaaproject</id>
            <url>http://repository.kaaproject.org/repository/internal/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.kaaproject.snapshots</id>
           <url>http://repository.kaaproject.org/repository/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add required repository as described [here](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/v0.10.0/pom.xml#L1416).